# Jquery ui dialog button submit issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

As a student of jquery ui I am having troubles finding how to set a dialog button to submit. On the input tags, I am using the type attribute to allow the browser to perform validation of ‘email’ and for the password, I’m using the pattern attribute and title.

```
                <input
                    type="email"
                    name="EMAIL_0000"
                    id="EMAIL_0000"
                    tabindex="12"
                    size="40"
                    placeholder="Username"
                    value=""
                    required/>
                <input
                    type="password"
                    name="PASSWORD_0000"
                    id="PASSWORD_0000"
                    tabindex="13"
                    pattern="<?php echo $PasswordPattern; ?>"
                    value=""
                    placeholder="Password"
                    title="See notes for valid password."
                    required/>
```

When a submit button is pressed, the user will see something like:

I cannot post the image because I don't have 10 reputation post images....

You will note there are two 'Sign On' buttons. The upper one (in the form area) is a type="submit" button. The lower one is created by the jquery ui dialog as follows:

```
    $(“#form_0000”).dialog({
      Var username = $(“#EMAIL_0000”).val(),
      Password=$(“#PASSWORD_0000”).val(),….
      buttons: {
          “Sign On”: function(){
// here I perform a $.ajax() to verify the email is in the data base. But the browser validation does not occur.
…….
    }
```

When the lower 'Sign On' button is pressed, no browser validation occurs, all validation must be done in the jquery dialog using $.ajax to access a php function to make server side data base queries.

From my research I don’t believe jQuery UI has the capability to allow the setting of the button type attribute. All I can see that can be done is set the name of the button.

At this point I believe my only option is to set a button in the form itself and indicate it’s a submit button and when pressed, the browser validation occurs, but then I have issues with verifying the existence of the email address and if the password is (I can show an alert box, but not the look and feel that I want) and once the processing of the is complete the dialog goes away, not allowing the user to select from one of the other ‘dialog’ buttons to join, etc.

Is there someone that has worked around the limitation that can provide some insight to a solution?

I think I can remove the lower 'Sign on' button and just use the forms submit button and maintain the processes off browser validation and programmable validation showing error messages and remaining at the dialog screen. I can move that code to

```
$( "#btnSignOn_0000" )
    .click(function() {
        // move dialog 'sign on' button code here.
    });
```

I would like to wait for some replies and avoid additional work if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch, sorry for leading you down the wrong path.  But since I did, I messed around with the code, and figured it out for you.

Uncomment the button you have in the dialog but do not display it by setting the css to:

```
#btnSignOn_0000 {
    display: none;
}
```

Now, in your dialog code, instead of $('formSignOn').submit(); use:

```
$("#form_0000").dialog({
      buttons: {
          “Sign On”: function(){
              $('#btnSignOn_0000').click();
          }
      }
});
```

The button is clicked, the validation is triggered, and the $('formSignOn').submit(function(){}) is not executed unless the form passes validation.

Comment: This did not work. You can see an example of what the issue is by going to http://www.delberthunterarboretum.org/TestSite/index.php and click the Sign In button on the top. Once there, you can click on the Sign On button and nothing happens.

Comment: Please see updated answer, and let me know if you get it ironed out.

Comment: I will be working on this tonight while watching TV. This is the last major hurdle before I can finish coding this site. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: James, we are 99% there. Everything works except when complete the dialog window closes even though there's an error (user not on file). You can test this yourself. I have an alert indicating the sign on failed and if you move the message box out of the way, you can see the error on the dialog window and when okay is clicked the dialog window closes. The dialog needs to remain active so if there is an error the user can click the Forgot Password or Sign Up button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution:

```
$('#formSignOn').submit(function( e ){
   e.preventDefault();
```

This prevents the submission to close the dialog window after the ajax function is performed.